# Rotativa --header-html using MVC view is not working

Tags: rotativa

I have recently started using Rotativa in my project. I have HTML page which will list out data in multiple tables.I need to display page number as footer which is working and display header using MVC view when user view this HTML as PDF. Problem that I'm facing is I dont see header being displayed. I can access the header URL standalone  and it loads fine but unable to load it within pdf. Can anyone please help me here?

Here are my action methods:

Below action method will render PDF:

```
    public ActionResult PrintBenificiaryForm()
    {
        PrintBenificiary p = new PrintBenificiary();
        p.TeamMemberInfo = GetSessionValues();
        p.IndividualBenefitPlans = GetBenefitPlansandIndividuals();

        string customSwitches = string.Format(" --footer-left \"[page] of [toPage]\" --footer-spacing -10 --footer-font-size \"10\"  --header-html  \"{0}\" ", Url.Action("PrintHeader", "Home", null, this.Request.Url.Scheme));
        return new ViewAsPdf("PrintBenificiaryForm", p)// { FileName = p.TeamMemberInfo.FirstName + " " + p.TeamMemberInfo.LastName + ".pdf" };
        {
            CustomSwitches = customSwitches
        };
        //return View(p);
    }
```

Action method for header

```
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult PrintHeader()
    {
        TeamMemberInfoModel t= GetSessionValues();
        return View(t);
    }
```

I have attached my view details and location of header file.[image]

[image]

Also I observed that when I pass third parameter in URL.action as new {area=""} as I get blank on PDF.

null returned when I passed area as empty to URL.Action method

But when I tried passing null , I get 401.2 unauthorized error.

This is URL returned when I passed to URL.Action method -http://localhost:3842/p/Home/PrintHeader

[image]

Comment: Instead of using a view as header html, I converted view to HTML page and used javascript XMLHttpRequest object to make a call to view. Now Javascript requesting controller is not working.